# How to place language switcher in header?

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I'm working on my website, in Wordpress. To say on the beggining, I'm no php coder, I just stambled on this thing working on my wordpress website. I bought a theme and installed Simple Language Switcher plugin. It works but I don't know how to place it where I want. I tried it everywhere in my header.php file but no luck. You can see in the image below where it is right now and where I want it (right, where I wrote HERE). And the link for the plugin:

http://www.mendoweb.be/blog/wordpress-plugin-simple-language-switcher/

[image]

This is the code for my language bar:

```
<?php if( function_exists( 'simple_language_switcher' ) ) { ?>
<div id="simple-language-switcher"><?php simple_language_switcher(); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here's my header.php file right now:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <main id="main">
 *
 * @package Terrifico
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<?php global $data; ?>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php if ($data['enable_favicon'] == 1 ) { ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $data['favicon']; ?>" type="image/x-icon" />

<?php } ?>
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

<?php terrifico_custom_styling(); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<?php if ($data['custom_css'] <> "") { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        <?php echo $data['custom_css']; ?>
    </style>
<?php } ?>  
</head> 

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="grid-container">
    <?php if ( $data['top_panel_enable'] == 1 ) { get_template_part( 'top-panel' ); }; ?>


<?php if( function_exists( 'simple_language_switcher' ) ) { ?>
<div id="simple-language-switcher"><?php simple_language_switcher(); ?></div>
<?php } ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="branding" class="<?php echo $data['layout']; ?>">
        <header id="header">
            <div id="logo">

                <?php if ( $data['text_logo_enable'] != 1 ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo $data['logo']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $data['logo_alt_text']; ?>"/></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php echo $data['logo_alt_text']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>      
            <?php if ( $data['menu_separated'] != 1 ) { ?>
                <div id="nav-holder">
                    <nav id="site-navigation-in" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main_navigation', 'container' => false,'menu_id'=>'menu-main-navigation','menu_class' => 'sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow', 'fallback_cb'=> 'terrifico_selectmenu', )); ?>
                    </nav><!--site-navigation-->
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var sf=jQuery.noConflict();
                sf(window).load(function(){
                // superFish
                sf('ul.sf-menu').supersubs({
                minWidth:    16, // minimum width of sub-menus in em units
                maxWidth:    40, // maximum width of sub-menus in em units
                extraWidth:  1 // extra width can ensure lines don't sometimes turn over
                })
                .superfish(); // call supersubs first, then superfish
                });
            </script>
    </div><!--branding-->
<?php if ( $data['menu_separated'] == 1 ) { ?>
    <div id="nav-holder" class="<?php echo $data['layout']; ?>">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main_navigation', 'container' => false,'menu_id'=>'menu-main-navigation','menu_class' => 'sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow', 'fallback_cb'=> 'terrifico_selectmenu', )); ?>
        </nav><!--site-navigation-->
    </div>
<?php } ?>
    <?php if ( $data['front_page_blog_index'] == 1 ) {?>
        <?php if (! is_home()) { ?>
            <?php if ( $data['page_header_on'] == 1 ) { ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'page-header' ); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php if ( $data['page_header_on'] == 1 ) { ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'page-header' ); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: within your conditional statement add, `die()` if the page shows up blank, you know that the function isn't defined. if it doesn't, you know that function isn't defined. Alternatively, inspect the console, does the encapsulating container appear? Proceed with same debugging as above. This will allow you to identify the issue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you need to edit is top-panel.php, in the same directory as header.php. It contains the expanded PHP code for that part of the header in your theme. You can see where it's referenced in header.php here, just above where you currently have the language bar code:

```
<?php if ( $data['top_panel_enable'] == 1 ) { get_template_part( 'top-panel' ); }; ?>
```

It's increasingly common for WordPress themes, when their designers want to keep everything tidy, to have usual theme parts like header.php, footer.php, etc. divided even further into sub-files. In other words, top-panel.php is to header.php, like header.php is to index.php.

First, **back up** any files you edit, then carefully insert the language bar code in **top-panel.php** so the file looks something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Terrifico
 */
global $data; ?>
    <div id="top-panel" class="<?php echo $data['layout']; ?>">
        <div id="info-box">
            <?php if ( $data['top_contact_enable'] == 1 ) { get_template_part( 'contact-bar' ); }; ?>
            <?php if(class_exists('Woocommerce')) { ?>
                <?php if ( $data['header_social_enable'] == 1 && $data['shopping_cart_enable'] == 0 ) { get_template_part( 'social-bar' ); }; ?>

                <?php if ( $data['shopping_cart_enable'] == 1 ) { get_template_part( 'shopping-cart' ); } ;?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php if ( $data['header_social_enable'] == 1 ) { get_template_part( 'social-bar' ); }; ?>
            <?php } ?>

    /* INSERT LANGUAGE BAR CODE */
    <?php if( function_exists( 'simple_language_switcher' ) ) { ?>
    <div id="simple-language-switcher"><?php simple_language_switcher(); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    /* END LANGUAGE BAR CODE */

        </div><!-- #info-box -->
    </div><!-- #top-panel -->
```

Basically, you want the language bar code to be *inside* the top-panel `<div>`. That's the div that contains the other divs for "Have any questions?", social icons, etc.

I don't actually have the theme installed to experiment with right now, but you'll probably have to play a little with the CSS or the code above to get it positioned perfectly. Hope I explained it clearly enough and that this helps.

Comment: This worked...partialy. I get it right there on the right of the phone number, but I need it all the way right. Also, I need it centered verticaly, and it's on the top. Also, and I don't know how, I see the /* INSERT LANGUAGE BAR CODE */ comment on the page. :)

Comment: That's strange. I may have used the multi-line comment markup incorrectly (always learning). But you can remove those INSERT and END lines, I just wanted to make it stand out in the example. Oops, hit submit by mistake... one moment...

Comment: Sorry, won't let me edit my comment from 6 minutes ago. The theme wasn't designed to have an extra div there, so you have to specify some styling for the div using css. I'd probably make the explanation too complicated (it's simple) but [here is one way to do it that should work](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). I would just play around with the top & left values until it appears exactly where you need it. Increasing "top" pushes it down however many pixels, and increasing "left" will push it further to the right. This will make it show up where you need it.